# Prestashop 1.7.7.3 and PHP 7.4 issues

Tags: php, cpanel, prestashop-1.7

I haven't really used my website in quite a while due to it giving me errors on use and I didn't have the time to review the issue. I am currently trying to get it to work and I am struggling to get it right.

I am running PrestaShop 1.7.7.3 with PHP 7.4 which seems to be a problem based on this picture provided by PrestaShop
[image]

As you can see, PHP 7.4 is not supported by PrestaShop 1.7.7.3, which is a problem because my cPanel instance doesn't allow me to use PHP 7.3 as the PHP version for my website. This means that I can't use the correct PHP version to allow me to operate my PrestaShop installation and, thus, upgrade it.

Is there any way to get this to work without having to completely reinstall PrestaShop because my PrestaShop is linked to my POS, and I will have to call someone out to get them linked again. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please ask if you have any questions and I will answer to the best of my ability.

EDIT: My website is not self-hosted, so I have limited access to the underlying computer. My MultiPHP Manager doesn't have any version of PHP before 7.4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change cPanel that allows to select 7.3. Or try using some virtual machines, like Docker. Just remember that 7.3 has reached EOL.

Comment: I don't really have the level of access to the hosting computer to change the cPanel, if that's what you're suggesting. I also don't think I can set up a Docker instance on the server, although I have no experience with setting Docker up on an server.

Comment: Can't you just upgrade prestashop?

Comment: Because of the PHP issues, I can't access any of PrestaShop's functionality, either through the web UI or through their command line. I am willing to perform a manual upgrade, but I wanted to hear if there are any alternative options that I could follow.

Comment: To keep PHP7.4 you should rewrite every piece of code not compatible, there is no other way. Clearly that is not a solution and upgrading is very risky because 99% of the times doesn't work correctly. Change hosting with someone that can provide you with PHP7.3 (7.2 even better for PS1.7.7.3) and take your time to evaluate the situation on building a new website, try a risky upgrade or keep the old one with EOL PHP.